# Ethereum:Smart Contract: How much ether should I send initially

Tags: blockchain

There is an option to send Ether while deploying smart contract(creating ERC20 token)[image]

How much Ether should one send to be able to successfully do transactions with ERC20 Token ?

Is there any relation or formula to calculate the amount of Ether that you need to send on the basis of total supply ?

**For Example**:- You have created one ERC20 Token and initializes total supply with 9999999000000000000000000.[image]

Then, how much ether you have to send ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to fund an ERC20 token contract with any ether at all.

In the context of an ERC20 token, ether is only used as a means to pay for "gas" (transaction fees). You will need to pay for gas to deploy the contract, and then people who use your token will pay for gas to interact with it, e.g. when transferring tokens.

Comment: That's OK. 
For example: The peoples who are using my ERC20 token doesn't have Ether in their account, then how can they transfer ERC20 tokens ?

Comment: They can't. No one can perform a transaction without paying for gas (in ether).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean transferring ERC20 tokens from a wallet to another, then you have no need to feed the ether field. You'll just need to feed the transaction with gas.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing ERC20 tokens with ether. Tokens are simply variables in smart contracts that get allocated to particular addresses in a mapping (see [here](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard) for an informative guide).

It is possible to send ether in the "value" field when creating a contract, however, the constructor of the contract will need to have the `payable` modifier.